# HTML video for products

Tags: product, video, product-video

Is there a way to add HTML video instead of relying on Youtube, Vimeo, ...
It's kinda unprofessional looking and it's not kinda hard to have a video tag that links to URL. Seems like this is supported as a Magento Commerce feature from documentation, I should be able to allow my own CDN link to do this kinda stuff. Seems like a very simple feature left out intentionally which looks bad on an open-source project

Comment: You want to add mp4 video?

Comment: yes, either by uploading or dropping a link from a CDN storage like AWS or Google cloud

Answer (score 2):

You can add a video by edit some code in  below plugin

```
https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-WysiwygDownloads
```

You need to add below code in di.xml file, file location **etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<item name="mp4" xsi:type="string">video/mp4</item>
```

For video tag, you need to add below code in this file **Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/OnInsert.php** after this line

$image = $helper->getImageHtmlDeclaration($filename, $asIs);

```
/*Replace mp4 video attribute src to video */
  $defaultFileTypes = array('mp4');
  foreach($defaultFileTypes as $a){
      if (strpos($image, $a) !== false) {
            $image= str_replace("img", 'video width="320" height="240" controls', $image);
            $image= str_replace("/>", '>', $image);
            $image.="</video>";
      }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try to verify it

Comment: is there a way to do the change in Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/OnInsert.php in your own theme or module file? that way I need to have the whole file with your snippet added, right?

Comment: Did you able to find the file?

Comment: yes, it's in ./vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/OnInsert.php , it's not recommended to edit files in vendor files cause composer would replace it

Comment: nvm, I think I found it in the same module and edited it

Comment: Is it working in module?

Comment: I think it's working, I can insert video files in the WYSIYG , but what I want is to show the video in the same gallery view as images. Exact same functionality as if it's Youtube video but with a custom link

Comment: For show video thumbnails, I need to check. Above answer add only video with tag

Comment: @MKoosej, did you get any solution for image

Comment: The video tag doesn't work exactly the way I want it, it's still adding image tag but the upload works, I'm just editing it manually in description to make it a video tag

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to host videos on your server as it may consume resources and large storage from your server, this is why even large ecommerce depends on 3rd party video providers to embed required videos. Youtube embedded videos give you the ability to style the embedded video so that you can style it according to your website design

However, if you decide to add videos manually, the easiest way to link videos to products is by using product custom attributes provided by magento, where you will save the video location as a string and call it whenever necessary.

Comment: does this mean I need to customize the theme to use that string in the video tag?